# Example of a smooth function $f$ with $f(0)=0, f'>0$ such that $ y(0)=a, y'(x)=f(x)$ has no global solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

Is there a simple(computable) example of a smooth function $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$, such that the solution of the ODE $$ y(0)=a, y'(x)=f(y)$$
cannot be defined for all $x\in \Bbb R$?

If the condition $f'(x)>0$ is replaced with $f'(x)\geq 0$ then $f(x)=x^3$ would be an example, but I can't find an example in the case $f'(x)>0$.

P.S. I need this result for a question about vector fields and flows

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing why $f(x)=x^3$ is a counterexample. Is $y=\frac{x^4}{4}+a$ not a solution defined for all $x$?

Comment: For your counterexample, $y(x)=x^4/4+a$ has $y(0)=a$ and $y'(x)=x^3=f(x)$.

Comment: @superckl  Sorry I've made a typo

Comment: @Andrei Sorry I've made a typo

Comment: Does 'smooth' imply 'integrable'? Then $y=a+\int\limits_{0}^{x} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ and no example exists. If not, any smooth and not intergable function would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can fairly easily make this happen for $a>0$ by requiring $y$ grow very fast. Choose $f(y)=e^y-1$ so that
$$y'(x)=e^y-1.$$
You can check the solution to this with the condition $y(0)=a$ is
$$y(x)=-\log(1+(e^{-a}-1)e^x).$$
One can then see this solution has a singularity at
$$x=a-\log(e^a-1)$$
when $a>0$. For $a<0$, you can use $f(y)=e^{-y}-1$.